# automatic datacontext transaction management

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I assumed when using DataContext in the following fashion I would get automatic rollback:

**UPDATE**  I actually called `SubmitChanges` twice but the question still applies.

```
public void UpdateUser(User user)
    {
        using (var context = new UserDataContext())
        {
            //update stuff.
            context.SubmitChanges();

            //update stuff.
            context.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

When something goes wrong there is no rollback.

Instead, to provide rollback I've implemented the following:

```
public void UpdateUser(User user)
    {
        var context = new UserDataContext();
        try
        {
            context.Connection.Open();
            context.Transaction = context.Connection.BeginTransaction();

            //update stuff.
            context.SubmitChanges();
            context.Transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            context.Transaction.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            context.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

which is *alot* more plumbing than I want. Is there a better way to indicate to DataContext you want automatic rollback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If not inside a external transaction (e.g. `TransactionScope`), `SubmitChanges` starts a transaction for you and should automatically rollback if an exception occurs.

Suggest you post the actual code causing the problem and the exception that occurs.

If you are performing multiple `SubmitChanges` and want them to be atomic, wrap in a `TransactionScope`:

```
using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
{
    blah1.SubmitChanges()

    blah2.SubmitChanges();

    ts.Commit();
}
```

Comment: I'm calling context.SubmitChanges() twice. 
The first time there are no errors. (this must mean it calls Transaction.Commit( ) for me?)

The second time I call SubmitChanges() it does not rollback the changes from the code before the first SubmitChanges(). That is by design I assume.

On the

Comment: Sorry, I hit enter and it added my comment b4 I was finished. What I meant, is in the real code //in 'update stuff' there is another call to SubmitChanges( )

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on SubmitChanges( ) under-the-hood.

Comment: Thanks Mitch, I didnt notice I was calling `SubmitChanges()` twice until after I posted. I may post another question regarding this however can you comment on calling SubmitChanges() changes multiple times within a using block? The only time I see it necessary is when you need to get db identifiers. The reason I had it (above) was I was doing a delete followed by an insert and it felt nicer to 'submit changes' after calling DeleteOnSubmit. ;)